# Cutting (not clipping) polygons with other polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover under MacOS 10.13 environment. I've got two polygon shapefile layers: one for natural areas and one for regions. I need to divide all natural areas, using the boundaries of the regions, without loosing any part. For example, in the following image, polygon A represents a natural area in shapefile `Natural_Areas` and polygons B and C represent the boundaries of two regions in shapefile `Regions`

[image]

I want to obtain a layer containing polygons 1, 2 and 3. I've tried with the clipping tool, but it returns a single polygon corresponding to polygons 2 and 3 joined (or, more precisely, not cut).

Comment: Have you tried using Union on A & B then clipping the output by polygon A?

Comment: Try Vector overlay - Union from the processing toolbox.

Comment: I found the choice of inputs unintuitive. For the union processing algorithm, Your polygon layer with B and C is the Input Layer, and A is the overlay. You then need to clip the result by A. This will still leave  region 1 to be found by Difference between the two layers.

Comment: Given how easy it is to create and then get rid of (temporary) layers produced by the processing tools in QGIS, you could use Polygons to lines on Regions and then Split with Lines on Natural Areas.

Comment: @ferus89 Your suggestion is THE answer. Please, write it in the answer section to validate it.

Comment: @user30184 Vector overlay leaves out not overlapping sectors

Comment: Simply follow up with extract by attributes

Comment: If it is acceptable to use also other tools that QGIS then the Polygon Overlay tool in OpenJUMP maybe does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a [union](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union) of polygons A and B

You can then [clip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) the union output using polygon A, returning the desired geometry.